# Woocommerce Category Images Thumbnails

Tags: css, wordpress, image, woocommerce, product

I have been battling with this for weeks now. For some reason there is code that has overridden the size/allignment of my woocommerce product images in category view. Without any code, it displays 2 products filling the entire space, even though I have a plugin running which should be showing 4 products per row.

I am currently using the following code as suggested by another user, which is getting me the correct sizes and showing 4 per row however it seems to randomly choose to display a different number on some rows leaving blank space where products should be.

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product:nth-child(2n), 
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product:nth-child(2n) 
{
   float: left; 
   clear: none!important; 
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.product, 
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product 
{
   width: 24%;
   margin: 0 0 2.992em 0.4875em;
   clear: none;
}
```

It can be seen occuring here https://www.raymondmayjewellers.com/product-category/accessories/ and in different ways on any other category page on the site.

Any ideas what is a) causing the initial issue (as partially solved by the code) or b) why the new code is returning rows less than 4 occasionally?

Comment: You want four products in one row right ?

Comment: Yeah that's the idea, it used to be just fine courtesy of the plugin but for some reason that now fails to override anything :/

And that code above is giving me 4 but only in some rows, other rows have gaps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether you are aware or not, but you are overriding too much lines and that might be causing issue.

Here is solution:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product{
 width:22% !important; /* this line is around 1031 line number*/
 margin: 0 0 2.992em 0.4875em;
 }
```

**Note**: I have removed `clear:none`.

Here is result :

[image: Result]

Comment: I don't seem to get that on my end? I have made the change on the website and the sizes seem correct however I am only getting 2 columns of products with 2 blank columns to the right? http://gyazo.com/5e2c74aa71cbf8965749717d804973b3

Comment: I have noticed that you have `.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product{clear:both}` which is culprit for that..please remove it or comment it and you kept width to 24% ..I would suggest you to give `!important` at the end of it.

Comment: Apologies for probably seeming very stupid, code is not my strong point. Where would I find this line to remove? Is it possible to override it in the theme rather then removing lines within css directly? I'm not sure where I would begin to look?

Comment: Can you please clear the caches ? It is conflicting very badly.

Comment: No worries, all caches should have just been cleared.

Comment: Can you just remove that class `.woocommerce ul.products li.product:nth-child(2n), 
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product:nth-child(2n) 
{
   float: left; 
   clear: none!important; 
}` completely and then replace `.woocommerce ul.products li.product, 
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product 
{
   width: 24%;
   margin: 0 0 2.992em 0.4875em;
   clear: none;
}` with this one `.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {width: 21.5%;clear: none !important;height: 252px;}` and tell me its output.

Comment: Looks like we've cracked it! I ended up mixing the two a little to get the spacing to work, but I'm happy. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Increase `width:24%` and `height:273px`.What is it giving ?
If you think It solved your case then please accept my answer so that when other people come across with this kind of issue, they can solve with the accepted answer.